# In a Node project global web properties could be used without compilation errors

Tags: node.js, typescript

In a node project currently global properties that exist only in the browser could be used without Typescript errors. For example:

```
window.innerWidth
document.getElementById("")
new Form Data()
```

How can we get a Typescript error in such cases. Our `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./out",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "types": ["node"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "exclude": ["./wdio.conf.ts"]
}
```

Comment: if `new Form Data()` does not give you errors at compile time, your compiler might not work.

Comment: can you please share full tsconfig and also the project relative path to file with new Form Data()?

Comment: @BorisTB, full tsconfig now included

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue. Just make sure your file with code has extension *.ts and not *.js

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build the project to check if there is any compilation errors.

if you are using yarn, then run

```
yarn tsc
```

in case you are using npm you can try

```
npx tsc
```